# The text of options of edittext selection mode are not completly visible

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface

This is my EditText's selection mode style.

[image]

As you can see it's texts are not completely visible.
This is my `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/onPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/onSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorError">@color/error</item>
    <item name="colorOnError">@color/onError</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/surface</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/DefaultTextStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DefaultButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/DefaultButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/enabledColor</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetTheme</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceBody1">@style/BodyAppearance</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/Subtitle1Appearance</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/Subtitle2Appearance</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/ButtonAppearance</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/Headline1</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/Caption</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="transparentPrimaryColor">@color/transparentPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/onSurface</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:popupWindowStyle">@style/PopupWindodwStyle</item>
</style>
```

I found out that deleting `textAppearanceButton` attribute somehow fixes the problem. This is how the value of `textAppearanceButton` look like:

```
<style name="ButtonAppearance" parent="MyApp">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/iransans_bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

I cannot delete that attribute because I've used it throughout my application. Does anyone know why this problem happens? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the style of the floating toolbar depends on the OS/launcher and is not app-dependent.

Comment: @ttyip You're wrong. For example it directly depends on the app's locale and also I found that the value of `textAppearanceButton` attribute somehow affects on the that.

Comment: @ttyip I edited the post please look at it.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this, have you found any documentation on this behaviour? Also, pretty sure `ButtonAppearance` shouldn't have `MyApp` as its parent.

Comment: Not Really but the problem was fixed by removing the attribute.

Comment: If you change the attributes drastically, say `textSize` to `40sp` and the font to something very different than `Roboto`, can you visually see a difference in the toolbar?